# Choose what to sync before turning on iCloud

Tags: icloud, data-synchronization, preferences

I want to only sync reminders and notes with iCloud. But when I turn it on, every possible option is enabled already by default. And syncing starts immediately, because the device must be online to enable iCloud.

How can I disable the unwanted sync options before enabling iCloud?